# Is it possible to embed JavaFX in HTML/JavaScript?

Tags: java, javascript, javafx

Is it possible to embed [JavaFX](http://javafx.com/) in HTML/JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible.

Check out:

http://javafx.com/samples/DraggableMP3Player/index.html

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have a JavaFX widget on a web page, then yes. You can use something like this: 
http://jfx.wikia.com/wiki/Applet_Example